# How to display Form query results in a ListView

Tags: django, python-3.x, listview, request

I've created a form where users will enter a date range. Once submitted it then needs to return a list from my database of people all those whose birthdays are within that date range. I'm fairly new to Django and I've tried but do not understand how to pass my "start_date & end_date" as kwargs from my form to ListView.

views.py:

```
class BirthdaysRangeFormView(FormView):
    template_name = 'snippets/date_selection_form.html'
    form_class = datefilterform

    def get_form_kwargs(self):
        kwargs = super(BirthdaysRangeFormView, self).get_form_kwargs()
        kwargs ['request'] = self.request 
        return kwargs

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        context = super().get_context_data(**kwargs)
        context['title'] = "Date Selection"
        context['header'] = "Please select date range"
        return context

    def form_valid(self, form):
        self.start_date = (form.cleaned_data['start_date'], People.next_birthday)
        self.end_date = (form.cleaned_data['end_date'], People.next_birthday)
        return self.redirect_to_results()

    def redirect_to_results(self):
        self.success_url = "dates:birthdays"
        return redirect(
            self.get_success_url(),
        )


class BirthdaysListView(BirthdaysRangeFormView, ListView):
    template_name = 'dates/birthdays.html',
    context_object_name = "person"
    person = True
    # queryset = People.objects.order_by('next_birthday')


    def get_queryset(self):
        test = ''
```

forms.py:

```
class datefilterform(forms.Form):
    model = People



    start_date = forms.DateField(
        input_formats=['%d/%m/%Y'],
        widget=DateTimePicker(
            options={"format": "DD/MM/YYYY", "pickTime": False})
    )

    end_date = forms.DateField(
        input_formats=['%d/%m/%Y'],
        widget=DateTimePicker(
            options={"format": "DD/MM/YYYY", "pickTime": False})
    )

    People.next_birthday = start_date
    People.next_birthday = end_date

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        self.request = kwargs.pop('request')
        super(datefilterform, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)

        self.helper = FormHelper()
        self.helper.form_id = 'main_form'
        self.helper.form_class ='form-horizontal'
        self.helper.label_class = 'col-lg-3'
        self.helper.field_class = 'col-lg-8'

        self.helper.layout = Layout(

            'start_date',
            'end_date',
            FormActions(
                Submit('submit', 'Submit'),
                Button('cancel', 'Cancel', css_class='cancel')
            )
        )

    def clean(self):

        cleaned_data = super().clean()
        start_date = cleaned_data.get("start_date")
        end_date = cleaned_data.get("end_date")

        if not check_end_date(start_date, end_date):
            raise forms.ValidationError(
                "Incorrect Dates entered, End date must be after start date"
            )
```

I've done simple ListViews before but I don't understand how to use "request" in class based views.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can simply access `self.request` in your class based views.

Rather you following format, so that you can handle both POST and GET request in the same view.

```
class MyView(FormView):
   template_name = 'some_template.html'
   success_url = '...'
   form_class = MyForm

   def get(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
      pass

   def post(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
      pass


   def form_invalid(self, form, **kwargs):
      pass


   def form_valid(self, form, **kwargs):
      pass
   .....
```

Comment: I don't understand what you mean by that like does it need to go in the def get_queryset or a def get etc. i did used to try `self.request = kwargs.get('start_date',
                          month_start(timezone.now()).date().strftime('%Y-%m-%d')
                         )`
              `self.request = kwargs.get('end_date',
                         month_end(timezone.now()).date().strftime('%Y-%m-%d')
                         )` would it be something along these lines

Comment: You are calling next view from one view? That's a bad practice @LewisCollins
I have prepared a code above. It may he helpful for you.

Comment: From the code above i don't understand how I'd be able to pass it all in one View